# Margins of a standalone chessboard using xskak

Tags: margins, standalone, xskak

I can't get rid of the white margins when producing a standalone chessboard using the xskak package (I have the same problem with the alternative chessboard package).

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\newchessgame[labelleft=false,labelbottom=false,id=show,setfen=1r3rk1/ppq1nppp/3b4/1B1pN3/3PpPQ1/2P5/PP5P/R1B2RK1 b - - 3 16, showmover=false,print] 

\end{document}
```

The output contains a white margins around the edge of the board (probably can't be seen with the white background):

[image]

I have checked related questions about getting rid of unwanted margins in standalone documents, but I can't relate those situations to the one above, where I hardly define/load anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xskak uses the chessboard package to print boards. How to set the margins in described in the chessboard documentation. You can set them by value or disable them completely:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\newchessgame[margin=false,labelleft=false,labelbottom=false,id=show,setfen=1r3rk1/ppq1nppp/3b4/1B1pN3/3PpPQ1/2P5/PP5P/R1B2RK1 b - - 3 16, showmover=false,print]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That also explains why using the package chessboard alone didn't help either ...